# How to explicitly push/pop to the C return stack?

Tags: c, gcc, stack, forth

Is there a way to explicitly push/pop data to the C return stack? (Ideally in  standard C, but a GCC-only solution would be ok too.)

I'm implementing a Forth in C, on a microcontroller that's very tight on RAM (kbytes, not Mbytes).

I'm allocating RAM for the data stack, but I'm hoping to save some RAM by sharing the Forth return stack with the C return stack, via explicit push/pops.

Can this be done in C?

Comment: "standard C" and "C return stack" don't go together.

Comment: *save some RAM by sharing the Forth return stack with the C return stack*, where do you think the call stack resides?

Comment: _I'm allocating RAM for the data stack, but I'm hoping to save some RAM by sharing the Forth return stack with the C return stack, via explicit push/pops_: this sounds very fishy to me, it's probably a bad idea

Comment: this seems like a bad idea (mixing domains like this... like the chance of corrupting your call stack for the sake of a register's worth of data seems folly), what you should do is learn the ABI for the microcontroller, there may always be some register that is unused by the C implementation... microcontrollers dont tend to have stable, well defined ABI's so if you change compilers or compiler version you may break something... if you want standard C, I would just leave it C.

Answer (score 2):

GCC has a [`__builtin_return_address`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) function, that's probably the closest you'll get.

Comment: I'm not sure what MCU the OP is using, but it's unlikely such MCU is supported by gcc

Comment: OP wrote "Ideally in standard C, but a GCC-only solution would be ok too."

Comment: How does this answer OP's question in ANY way? He wants to push/pop on the call stack (even though it is fundamentally flawed). This builtin returns the return address, not even the address of the return address. If you think this can be used to achieve what OP wants, some explanation should be added.

Answer (score 0):

I consider Forth as an excursion from C into an assembler program. There probably is a c-register that serves as a stack pointer. If you take care to properly clean up that stack before returning to C, you probably can use it while you are in your assembler code (Forth). You must study the c-compiler to make sure this is possible and to know which register is the stack pointer. Also take care to restore any registers that c wants kept.

Answer (score -1):

There are many FORTH-in-C systems around, ask Google or rummage in github. There are many design problems (not just this one!) that you''l have to solve, look at the previous solutions.